# Incorporating a function into an ODE integration

Tags: python, function

This question is probably very simple but for the life of me I can't figure it out. Basically, I have a neuron whose voltage I'm modeling, but I have it receiving input spikes from other neurons randomly. So a friend of mine helped to create a function that essentially has some excitatory neurons provide a random Poisson spike which increases the voltage randomly and some inhibitory neurons providing downward spikes lowering the voltage. I've included the code below. Basically the step I'm trying to figure out how to do is how to make the I_syn term in the iterative step work. I would normally think to just write `I_syn[i-1]`, but that gives me an error:

```
'function' object has no attribute '__getitem__'.
```

So I'm sure this question is really simple, but it's a problem I don't know how to overcome. How do I get this program to iterate the `I_syn` term properly so I can do a basic iterative scheme of an ODE while including a function defined previously in the code? It's important because I'll likely have more complicated neuron equations in the near future, so it would be much better to write the functions beforehand and then call them into the iteration step as needed. Thank you!

```
from numpy import *
from pylab import *

## setup parameters and state variables
T       = 50                  # total time to simulate (msec)
dt      = 0.125               # simulation time step (msec)
time    = arange(0, T+dt, dt) # time array
t_rest  = 0                   # initial refractory time

## LIF properties
Vm      = zeros(len(time))    # potential (V) trace over time
Rm      = 1                   # resistance (kOhm)
Cm      = 10                  # capacitance (uF)
tau_m   = Rm*Cm               # time constant (msec)
tau_ref = 4                   # refractory period (msec)
Vth     = 1                   # spike threshold (V)
V_spike = 0.5                 # spike delta (V)

## Stimulus
I       = 1.5                 # input current (A)
N = 1000
N_ex = 0.8*N #(0..79)
N_in = 0.2*N #(80..99)
G_ex = 0.1
K = 4

def I_syn(spks, t):
    """
    Synaptic current
    spks = [[synid, t],]
    """
    if len(spks) == 0:
        return 0

    exspk = spks[spks[:,0]<N_ex] # Check for all excitatory spikes
    delta_k = exspk[:,1] == t # Delta function
    if np.any(delta_k) > 0:
        h_k = np.random.rand(len(delta_k)) < 0.90 # probability of successful transmission
    else:
        h_k = 0

    inspk = spks[spks[:,0] >= N_ex] #Check remaining neurons for inhibitory spikes
    delta_m = inspk[:,1] == t #Delta function for inhibitory neurons
    if np.any(delta_m) > 0:
        h_m = np.random.rand(len(delta_m)) < 0.90
    else:
        h_m = 0

    isyn = C_m*G_ex*(np.sum(h_k*delta_k) - K*np.sum(h_m*delta_m))

    return  isyn

## iterate over each time step
for i, t in enumerate(time):
  if t > t_rest:
      Vm[i] = Vm[i-1] + (-Vm[i-1] + I_syn*Rm) / tau_m * dt
  if Vm[i] >= Vth:
    Vm[i] += V_spike
    t_rest = t + tau_ref

## plot membrane potential trace
plot(time, Vm)
title('Leaky Integrate-and-Fire Example')
ylabel('Membrane Potential (V)')
xlabel('Time (msec)')
ylim([0,2])
show()
```

Answer (score 0):

`I_syn` is just a function so using `I_syn[i-1]` will throw this error:

```
'function' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

If what you are looking for is a return value from the function, then you should first call it and then access what you want.

```
# pass related arguments as well since the function expects it
I_syn(arg1, arg2)[i-1]
```

Comment: So I tried I_syn(spks,t)[i-1], and get the error that spks isn't defined. I tried then to just use I_syn(t)[i-1] and I get "I_syn() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)." I assume then the best option is to define "spks"  but I'm unsure how I should do that appropriately for this problem

Comment: It seems you need to understand the basics first. When you pass `spks` in the function is it defined somewhere already or not? I guess it is not and that's why you are getting this error. First define `spks`, as what the function expects it to be. And, then call the function with it in arguments.

Comment: Ok so I think I understand what you're saying to do, except I'm not sure what the function expects spks to be since I assume it's acting as a parameter basically. So spks should be basically a list of the 1000 neurons beforehand and the times at which they fire (I believe that's how it's written), but I'm not sure how to define that outside of the function (Sorry, I'm a real novice at this)